# resourceData returns null for microsoft graph API change notificaiton for SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I have created a change notification for SharePoint "Access Requests" list. I am getting Notifcation when change ocurred in list. but i am not getting resourceData as usually we got with Graph api change notification payload.

please refer the below Out Put.

{"value":[{"subscriptionId":"a2f0888f-3bb9-4547-b0a5-42814751c3da","clientState":"SecretClientState","resource":"sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}","tenantId":"2af0e6f9-fc72-45c7-98bb-98dc4738b53f","resourceData":null,"subscriptionExpirationDateTime":"2021-03-10T09:48:43.9049967-08:00","changeType":"updated"}]}

Can any else faced this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

Change notifications with resource data is not supported for SharePoint lists. Your application will only get notified a change has occurred but it's then up to your application to query SharePoint back through Microsoft graph to get the latest data. If you feel like this feature should be supported for SharePoint too, please create an idea on https://Microsoftgraph.uservoice.com

Comment: the resource data is not supported but shouldn't the id of the changed record be posted with the notification? the id sit outside of resource data.

In the question there's also no Id present for the application to handle the change..

Comment: The resource field provides the relative URL (from scheme://host/version) to the resource. The idea is to query the resource to get the additional details your application might need.